How do you create an ffmpeg lossless image without re-encoding?
I'm using the command below but not sure if it’s really lossless and without re-encoding? Is there specific command to create lossless image and without re-encoding? I'm new to this.
ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png


It's the best .png can be, I'd imagine. You can add -crf=0 to make sure it's best quality possible.

PNG is a lossless format, it requires no additional parameters to ensure lossless encoding.
Assumed quality parameters for PNG output with other programs are simply compression settings. You can compress lossless formats, including PNG, to reduce file size. This does not affect the quality, only file size and encoding time.
To set PNG compression values in ffmpeg use -compression_level followed by a value between 0 to 100. 0 equals no compression, 100 (the default) equals maximum compression.
Also, you are creating a PNG from nothing, so you are encoding, not re-encoding. You would need to input an existing file to re-encode.
